# maintaining state file for multiple terraform module

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

I am building a terraform for my production infrastructure. My module directory structure is like below
 `main.tf`
 `variable.tf`
 `terraform.tfvars`
  `|----->AKS/main.tf`
  `|----->Mysql/main.tf`
  `|----->Kafka/main.tf`

I am facing issues to design state files for the above structure. While building AKS we have to run manually/script to create state file ("We cannot create this storage account and blob container using Terraform itself since).

is there any way to define state file at all module-level while deploying complete stack without running below command in child module.

`az storage container create --name terraform-state --account-name mytf --account-key xxxxx`

Comment: I don't think so this is possible..terraform backend doesn't supports vars.....but you can check terraform workspace..https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating storage container for each state file is not the right thing to do.

Two solutions I can think of:

- User [terraform workspace -h](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) : It's a logical way to organize.
- Pass the backend key dynamically while doing terraform init something like below, in this way you can create state file by specific name.

  > terraform init backend-config=backend.tfvars
  >   backend-config="key=${AKS|Mysql|Kafka|any-variable}.{any-variable}.tfstate"